# How to insert the results of sp_executesql into a table which to be created during the insert?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have sql statements which I capture through the profiler from Linq to SQL. They look like EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT..... ' and the statements include the types of the parameters and single quotes.

Is there a way to get the output from such statement and insert it into a table which doesn't exist?
Similar to SQL's  `Select column1, column2.. into #tablename from table2` where SQL Server creates the output table during the insert? I do this with different statements multiple times during a session so I am looking for the quickest way which involves least amount of typing. (SQL Server 2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) trick should do.

```
SELECT
  *
INTO
  #tt
FROM
  OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server=(local);UID=<login>;Pwd=<password>;','SET FMTONLY OFF; <your query>;');
```

In place of <your query> you should be able to place the `EXEC sp_executesql N'...'`. HTH.

Comment: I don't know why you have fmtonly setting in there. I used openrowset earlier and kept getting errors because of the single quotes. This is my solution now using double quotes:  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  SELECT
  *
INTO
  #tt
FROM
  OPENROWSET("SQLNCLI","Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;","exec sp_executesql N'select * from ....';");

  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
select * from #tt

Comment: @Tony_Henrich Hi Tony, I had problems once with not having that in front of the query once, so I keep adding it in every instance I use it. Quite possible that in other environments it is not necessary. You were probably having problems with the single quotes because you have to double your single-quotes inside the parameters if you use single quotes. You don't need to if you use double-quotes. Hard to get this in words with all the quotes :). Happy to help!